# Is endlocal required before exit?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following "function" in a batch scripts:

```
:myfunction
    setlocal
    set _variable=%*
    :: do something with %_variable%
    endlocal
    exit /B 0
```

Note the `setlocal` / `endlocol` pair.

Is `endlocal` required here? Or is it redundant? Does `exit` end the localization implicitly?

**Bonus question**:
Can this question be answered without testing the behavior, for example by  citing an official source?

Comment: There is a reason why batchers use `endlocal&set %1=%Whatever%&Goto :Eof` when they **want** to pass back a variable content from a sub. This works only on the  same line, when still in the scope of the sub.

Comment: `endlocal` is implicitly executed when exiting a batch file (by `exit`, `exit /B`, `goto :EOF` or reaching its end) and when returning from a called batch-file or sub-routine (run by `call`) as often as required to revert all (nested) environment localisations done by `setlocal`.

Comment: Regarding your bonus question, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Additionally, had you read the comment in direct response to you, beneath my answer, and looked at the official link within it, it part answers your request, and implies what is noted from the answer I provided, and aschipfl's comment above.

Comment: Your question is answered by first paragraph of help of command __SETLOCAL__ which is output on running in a command prompt window `setlocal /?`. Every Windows standard command outputs the command help on running it with `/?`. Try it out with `endlocal /?`, `exit /?` and `set /?`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not really sure whether there's something you're wanting to ask, yet haven't, but given your posted script you could have tested it thus:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "_variable="
Call :MyFunction "argument"
Set _variable
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:MyFunction
SetLocal
Set "_variable=%~1"
Exit /B 0
```

If you receive a message stating `Environment variable _variable not defined` then `SetLocal` was closed by the `Exit` command, i.e. `Exit` implicitly ended the localization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I could test it. But, I was hopping someone would point me to a official documentation about exit and ending the localization.

Comment: @sergej, technically though, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. _(as a side note to that, official documentation would likely reside on [Microsoft's servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/endlocal) or in their documentation, not `ss64.com`)_.

Answer (score 5):

Consider two batch files, `a.bat` and `b.bat`. The batch file `a.bat` calls `b.bat` and also calls a local subroutine `:c`.

```
   @echo off
   rem -------------
   rem This is a.bat
   rem -------------
   echo Outer A=%A%
   setlocal
   set A=Value_A
   echo Local A=%A%
   echo Calling b.bat
   call b.bat
   echo Back from b.bat
   echo A=%A%
   echo Calling subroutine :c
   call :c
   echo Back from subroutine :c
   echo A=%A%
   exit /b
:c
   setlocal
   set A=Value_C
   echo Inside subroutine :c A=%A%
   exit /b
```

```
   @echo off
   rem -------------
   rem This is b.bat
   rem -------------
   setlocal
   set A=Value_B
   echo Inside b.bat A=%A%
```

Running `a.bat` produces:

```
C> a.bat
Outer A=
Local A=Value_A
Calling b.bat
Inside b.bat A=Value_B
Back from b.bat
A=Value_A
Calling subroutine :c
Inside subroutine :c A=Value_C
Back from subroutine :c
A=Value_A
```

Note that there is no `endlocal` in sight.